# How to fix the gnu make error about a header file location

Tags: gnu-make

I have the following output:

```
compiling platform/msm8974/common/cpu.c
In file included from platform/msm8974/include/asm/types.h:4:0,
                 from platform/msm8974/include/linux/types.h:4,
                 from platform/msm8974/include/linux/list.h:4,
                 from platform/msm8974/include/module.h:9,
                 from platform/msm8974/common/cpu.c:13:
platform/msm8974/include/asm-generic/int-ll64.h:11:25: fatal error: bitsperlong.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [../build-msm8974/platform/msm8974/common/cpu.o] Error 1
```

My understanding is that int-1164.h refers to bitsperlong.h and make does not see it in that directory. Right? 
Well I see the file in this directory when I do an 'ls'. In fact I put the file in the same directory myself. What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it please?
I have tried cleaning the build environment a couple of times. I am stuck; I am not sure why that file is not visible to make or why I get this error.

@Etan Reisner- Hi Etan, I put the file bitsperlong.h in the same directory.

@Brian McFarland- Hey Brain, Thanks. So if I want to add it to actual makefile it would be something like:

```
#include /AbsolutePathtomyDesiredDirectory
```

Right?

Comment: You put what file where?

Comment: You need to make sure `bitsperlong.h` is in a directory in your include path(s).  You can add directories to search for headers with `-I`